# Where is the Gnome classic menu metadata?

Tags: gnome, globalmenu

After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 my Gnome menu (as in classic-menu-indicator) is missing all my customized entries. The .desktop files are all still in .local/share/applications but the metadata to integrate them into the menu seems to be missing. So my questions

a) Where is the metadata defining the menu structure and entries kept?

b) How can I integrate my existing .desktop files into the menu

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself with the help of the [freedesktop.org spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html)

There was a `gnome-applications.menu` in `~/.config/menus` and as the env variable `XDG_MENU_PREFIX` was set to `"gnome-"` the gnome-version trumped my `applications.menu.`

Renaming my `applications.menu` to `gnome-applications.menu` solved the problem